# Generalized Least Squares using Moore Penrose pseudo inverse

Tags: generalized-least-squares, matrix-inverse

I'm using GLS to fit a model where some independent variables are strongly correlated. Therefore my covariance matrix is singular. I have found that Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse can be used to find an inverse solution even an matrix is singular. Is it safe to replace the inverse of the covariance matrix with a pseudo inverse of the correlation matrix when using a GLS?

Comment: If we have strongly correlated feature it is a better idea to actually use proper regularisation (e.g. Tikhonov regularisation). I have made some further points on the matter  [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/394734).

Comment: another possible approach is to  what's highly correlated and eliminate redundant variables.

Comment: Thank you both. We currently remove correlated variables but this is not ideal. We fit to 1000+ different vectors y using this model: b=(X^t O^-1 X)^1 X^t O^1 y. The variables are not correlated between the different y's, so for some vectors of y we might remove very relevant variables. Because we fit many different y’s, we calculate the (X^t O^-1 X)^-1 X^t O^-1 part once. I understand that Generalized Tikhonov might give a better fit but if I understand correctly, I would need to determine a Tikhonov matrix per y. Hence the question can I replace O^-1 in this model with the pseudoinverse O^+?

Comment: @Patrick: Thank you for this clarification. Yes, you should be fine. Are you sure you cannot attack this pre-computing $X^TO^{-1}$ in one go though? Depending on your platform their might be some better options than simply doing manual matrix inversions and multiplications.

Comment: @usεr11852 Thank you for your answer, I’m happy to hear this. I’m also intrigued by your remark to directly calculate X^t O^-1 do you happen to know a source that explains this further?

Comment: Depending on what you want to solve there might be faster and equally robust methods. For example maybe attacking this through $LDL^T$ is faster as it will still work with semi-PD matrices. When the matrix game gets serious (and I do not have MATLAB, i.e. wrap things beatifully around Intel's MKL) [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicLinearAlgebraDecompositions.html) is a good weapon of choice. (Yes, some  C++ will be needed.)

Comment: Thank you, I will keep this in mind if further optimizations are needed.

Comment: This video describes how the SVD can be used to solve linear systems of equations. In particular, it is possible to solve nonsquare systems (overdetermined or underdetermined) via least squares regression and the pseudoinverse. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02QCtHM1qb4

Answer (score 2):

You can compute a solution using the Moore-Penrose inverse in place of the (non-existing) usual inverse. That is known to give a minimum-norm solution. That is, with the linear model in matrix form (assuming iid errors)
$$
   Y = X\beta + \epsilon
$$ (you write *generalized least square* so presumably the covariance matrix of the error term $\epsilon$ is not of the form $\sigma^2 I$, but everything can be generalized to that case.) Then the least squares solution is $\hat{\beta}= (X^TX)^{-1} X^T Y$, but this only exists if $X^T X$ is invertible. Failing that, the equation system 
$$  X^T X \beta = X^T Y
$$ has infinitely many solutions, and we could pick any of those. But it is argued that when the estimated model is used for prediction,  it is advantageous that $\beta$ is "small", since $\beta$ will also amplify errors. So it is natural to choose the solution of minimal norm $ ||\beta||^2 = \sum_j \beta_j^2$. That solution is found by using the Moore-Penrose inverse. Details can be found here [Solve $X^TX b = a$ for $b$ using $XX^T$ for a short and wide matrix $X$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159729/solve-xtx-b-a-for-b-using-xxt-for-a-short-and-wide-matrix-x/159734#159734).

The you ask if it is *safe to replace the inverse of the covariance matrix with a pseudo inverse of the correlation matrix when using a GLS*? Well, **it is safe**. Denote the Moore-Penrose inverse of $X^TX$ with $(X^TX)^+$ and the minimum norm estimator by $\beta^*$. Then 
\begin{align} \DeclareMathOperator{\C}{\mathbb{Cov}}
   \C \beta^* &=& \C\left\{ (X^TX)^+ X^T Y\right\} \\
              &=& (X^TX)^+ X^T \sigma^2 I X (X^T X)^+ \\
              &=& \sigma^2 (X^TX)^+ X^TX  (X^TX)^+ \\
              &=& \sigma^2 (X^TX)^+
\end{align}
where we in the last line used a basic property of the [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse), that $A^+ A A^+ = A^+$.

Comment: How does this answer the question about whether computing the generalized inverse of the *covariance*--which is a key part of the GLS solution--is correct?

Comment: @whuber see the edits

Comment: I think we have different interpretations of the question.  The "covariance" in this case is not the covariance of the parameter estimates: it's the *specified* covariance matrix of the *errors,* often denoted $W.$  The [standard formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_square) is $$\hat\beta=(X^\prime W^{-1} X)^{-1} X^\prime W^{-1} Y.$$ An inverse of $W$ appears twice.  The question supposes $W$ is not invertible and asks whether replacing "$W^{-1}$" everywhere by its generalized inverse still produces the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for this extensive answer. @whuber was indeed correct that I want to replace the inverse of covariance matrix with the pseudo inverse so $W^{-1}$ with $W^+$. If I understand correctly this is answered by the last section that you added.

Comment: Sorry, Im not sure its solved, I will try to resolve that version too. Its a bit more complicated